# Get one unique List<T> from three non-unique List<T>'s

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have three lists of `User`:

```
ICollection<User> listOne = _somewhere.GetUsers(1);
ICollection<User> listTwo = _somewhere.GetUsers(2);
ICollection<User> listThree = _somewhere.GetUsers(3);
```

The "unique" identifier to compare on is a string field called "Email".

How do i get a unique list from the three (e.g no dupes).

I've got a unique list from **two** lists before using `Except`, but not sure how to do it with three? Do i have to use `Except` on the first two, then do it again on the result of the first two and the third?

**Also, i should mention** that the list of User's comes from external Web API calls, and there is no guarantee that each list has a unique list of email addresses.

So it's like i need two steps:

1. In each list, get rid of dupes
2. Combine the three unique lists to get one unique list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it does not matter which user you pick from the list of users with the same e-mail, you can do this:

```
var res = listOne.Concat(listTwo).Concat(listThree)
    .GroupBy(u => u.Email)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Again, this assumes that when e-mail addresses are the same, it does not matter which user you'd pick.

Comment: You mean `.Concat` (from `IEnumerable<T>`) not `.Concatenate` right?

Comment: Went with this because it's the most straightforward, and it works. Not saying this is any better than any other answer here, but this is the one i went with.

Comment: @RPM1984 You are absolutely right, it is Concat, not Comcatenate. I edited the answer to correct this mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just union the lists and do a dedupe (using `Distinct()`) once on the combined list.

```
var uniqueList = listOne.Union(listTwo)
                        .Union(listThree)
                        .Distinct(new EmailComparer())
                        .ToList();
```

For the comparer could be as simple as this:

```
class EmailComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y)
    {
        return x.Email == y.Email;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User obj)
    {
        return obj.Email.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out in comments `Distinct()` is not needed if we apply the custom email comparer to `Union()`:

```
var emailComparer = new EmailComparer();
var uniqueList = listOne.Union(listTwo, emailComparer)
                        .Union(listThree, emailComparer)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Note: Distinct is overkill. Union already covers that with a valid Equals / GetHashCode (or EqualityComparer).

Comment: You'll have to pass in that comparer to the `Union()` calls if you do that since they are treated as sets.  That would also make the `Distinct()` call unnecessary since they should already be distinct.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Good point, would have to apply the custom comparer there though as well - will update answer.

Answer (score 2):

First define how we want to define uniqueness:

```
private class EmailEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
  public bool Equals(User x, User y)
  {
    //don't bother shortcutting on reference equality, since if they come from
    //separate web-calls it's unlikely to happen, though it could
    //with some optimisations on the web-client code.
    if(x == null)
      return y == null;
    if(y == null)
      return false;
    return x.Email == y.Email;
  }
  public int GetHashCode(User obj)
  {
    return obj == null ? 0 : obj.Email.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Now call `Distinct` on the items of each, and put the results into a list:

```
var distinctUnion = listOne.Concat(listTwo).Concat(listThree).Distinct(new EmailEqComparer());
```